# Artin on law of compositions

Tags: matrices, group-theory

This is a very basic question, but I can't follow fully what Artin was getting at in the following paragraph.

> It is important to know right away that $ab$ stands for a certain element of $S$, namely for the element obtained obtained by applying the given law to the elements denoted by $a$ and $b$. If the law is matrix multiplication and if $a = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $b = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $ab$ denotes the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. **Once the product $ab$ has been evaluated, the elements $a$ and $b$ cannot be recovered from it.**

The last line is what confuses me. If inverses exist, then I can recover $a$ by multiplying $ab$ by $b^{-1}$ on the right. I can recover $b$ by multiplying $ab$ by $a^{-1}$ on the left. If I'm just giving the matrix $ab$ in the form $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ without being told what $a$ and $b$ are, I can't say immediately what $a$ and $b$ are, and the law of composition is surely an injective function. I could just as well use $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $I$ instead of the $a$ and $b$ above.

I can't tell if he's referring to the fact that $S$ may not be a group and may not admit inverses or that, if just given this matrix, the law may not be injective. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: If I gave you the answer, how would you know what $b^{-1}$ is? For example, I multiply two numbers and get $84$. Which two numbers did I multiply?

Comment: Ok, so what Artin means is only that the resulting matrix is given, but not that it was composed by $a$ and $b$? So it isn't given as $ab$, but as some other matrix, say $c$.

Comment: That is correct. I believe his point is that $ab$ is not a new element but that composition evaluates to an element in $S$. Without the rest of the text, I can't be certain.